# Load php file wth xml header

Tags: php, xml

I have a php file with an xml header and xml code, named test.php.

```
    <?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');

$file = file_get_contents('http://api.tradedoubler.com/1.0/vouchers.xml?token=removed');
echo $file;

?>
```

The xml from the API looks something like this:

```
<voucherList>
  <voucher>
    <id>115</id>
    <programId>111</programId>
    <programName>Program 111</programName>
    <code>AF30C5</code>
    <updateDate>1332422674941</updateDate>
    <startDate>1332370800000</startDate>
    <endDate>1363906800000</endDate>
    <title>Voucher number one</title>
    <shortDescription>Short description of the voucher.</shortDescription>
    <description>This is a long version of the voucher description.</description>
    <voucherTypeId>1</voucherTypeId>
    <defaultTrackUri>http://clk.tradedoubler.com/click?a(222)p(111)ttid(13)</defaultTrackUri>
    <siteSpecific>True</siteSpecific>
  </voucher>
  <voucher>
    <id>116</id>
    <programId>111</programId>
    <programName>Program 111</programName>
    <code>F90Z4F</code>
    <updateDate>1332423212631</updateDate>
    <startDate>1332370800000</startDate>
    <endDate>1363906800000</endDate>
    <title>The second voucher</title>
    <shortDescription>Short description of the voucher.</shortDescription>
    <description>This is a long version of the voucher description.</description>
    <voucherTypeId>1</voucherTypeId>
    <defaultTrackUri>http://clk.tradedoubler.com/click?a(222)p(111)ttid(13)url(http://www.example.com/product?id=123)</defaultTrackUri>
    <siteSpecific>False</siteSpecific>
    <landingUrl>http://www.example.com/product?id=123</landingUrl>
  </voucher>
</voucherList>
```

How do I load this file as an xml?

The following doesn't work:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.php');
echo $xml;
```

I just get a white page.

The test file is saved as php, as it's dynamic. It's loading data from the tradedoubler api.

Maybe it's the way the api-data is loaded?

Comment: Could you post an example file? Maybe strip some of the data, just to give me an idea.

Comment: Show your source file. And what do you want to do with the xml? Just using `echo` on an object/array tree may not work. Also have you enabled error_reporting? (First step when getting a blank page!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried your example source file and did `print_r($xml);`
I actually get an output.

So please try `print_r($xml)`;

I can access your XML by(example, worked for me)

```
$xml->voucher[0]->id;
```

That's because $xml is an object, inside this object there are arrays(like voucher) and inside this array there are objects again.

**Edit:** You altered your OP a lot so:

I tried your original example with a x.php:

```
<?php

    header('Content-type: text/xml');

    $file = simplexml_load_file('test.php');
    echo $file->voucher[0]->id;

?>
```

And in test.php I gout your xml:

```
    <voucherList>
  <voucher>
    <id>115</id>
    <programId>111</programId>
    <programName>Program 111</programName>
    <code>AF30C5</code>
    <updateDate>1332422674941</updateDate>
    <startDate>1332370800000</startDate>
    <endDate>1363906800000</endDate>
    <title>Voucher number one</title>
    <shortDescription>Short description of the voucher.</shortDescription>
    <description>This is a long version of the voucher description.</description>
    <voucherTypeId>1</voucherTypeId>
    <defaultTrackUri>http://clk.tradedoubler.com/click?a(222)p(111)ttid(13)</defaultTrackUri>
    <siteSpecific>True</siteSpecific>
  </voucher>
  <voucher>
    <id>116</id>
    <programId>111</programId>
    <programName>Program 111</programName>
    <code>F90Z4F</code>
    <updateDate>1332423212631</updateDate>
    <startDate>1332370800000</startDate>
    <endDate>1363906800000</endDate>
    <title>The second voucher</title>
    <shortDescription>Short description of the voucher.</shortDescription>
    <description>This is a long version of the voucher description.</description>
    <voucherTypeId>1</voucherTypeId>
    <defaultTrackUri>http://clk.tradedoubler.com/click?a(222)p(111)ttid(13)url(http://www.example.com/product?id=123)</defaultTrackUri>
    <siteSpecific>False</siteSpecific>
    <landingUrl>http://www.example.com/product?id=123</landingUrl>
  </voucher>
</voucherList>
```

And it still works for me. So if you still got a blank page the error must be somewhere else. Do you have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` turned on?

Answer (score 0):

simplexml_load_file() will load the xml file as an object. If you echo an object it should just say "Object" in the output. If you are getting a white page, there's a good chance something went wrong (ie: check error logs).

You can `print_r($xml);` to view the contents of the XML object (if it's set correctly).

If you get output from your print_r statement, you can start accessing specific nodes and elements:

```
echo $xml->node[index]->element;
```

and so on.

Comment: I am guessing the xml content isn't set correctly, as I still get white page. I have updated the OP.

Comment: Can you invoke your xml PHP page directly? If so, you can copy/paste the output into test.xml and try the same code you use on that static xml file.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Which was why I tried with the test.php. The tradedoubler xml must be faulty somehow?

Comment: Sorry to interrupt but as I posted I tried your example and it worked perfectly for me. Did you try my example? Even if I keep your header('Content-type: text/xml'); and use simplexml_load_file('test.php'); it works! I can echo $xml->voucher[0]->id; or $file->voucher[0]->id; what ever you call your variable now..

Answer (score 0):

the xml file loads fine and the output is not empty but just some new lines.

try

```php
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Edit:
Maybe your php configuration blocks file_get_contents for external urls (allow_url_fopen = Off). Try to get it with curl, or an direct request like this:

```php
$xml = '';
$fp = fsockopen('api.tradedoubler.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET /1.0/vouchers.xml?token=removed HTTP/1.1\r\n"
         . "Host: api.tradedoubler.com\r\n"
         . "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $xml .= fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}

if ($xml != '') {
    $xmlObject = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    if ($xmlObject) {
        // do something nasty! or just echo $xml->asXML();
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't actually help him to access the XML elements in PHP.

Comment: oh sorry i over read that he tries to use file_get_contents with an external url to get the xml...